# Backup The Ethereum Wallet Account names

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

As you know, the keystore folder stores account keys. So if I want open my accounts(which was created by Linux client) by MacOS client I need just copy the keystore folder. But in this way my specified account names is lost.
Are there any ways migrate the names between the Ethereum Wallet clients?